# How to start Unity3D Pro with Wine

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, 14.10, license

I have a Ubuntu 14.10 Dual-boot with Windows 8.1 Pro and I have Unity Pro 4.5.5 on my Windows OS. I have the activated Unity on Windows and I tried to start it in Wine but it says "Error initializing license system". How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the file `Unity_v5.x.ulf` to d`rive_c/users/Public/Application Data/unity` in your wine folder.

If there is no such folder in that path so create. It should works!